# MongoDB aggregation from nested array of objects

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm working on a school project and I need to join the *subject* document with *content* documents on *contentId*. However, I can't use mongoose because I'm working with a stack provided by the school. Here's an example to explain my problem:

Example *subject* document:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('000000000000000000000100')
  name: "My subject"
  description: "Lorem ipsum..."
  language: "en",
  topics: [
    {
      id: ObjectId('000000000000000000000200'),
      name: "The first topic",
      description: "Lorem ipsum...",
      content: [
        {
          contentId: ObjectId('000000000000000000000300'),
          visibility: true,
        },
        {
          url: "stackoverflow.com",
          title: "Stack Overflow",
          type: "website"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Example *content* document:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('000000000000000000000300'),
  title: "Example content",
  description: "Example course in MongoDB",
  url: "http://example.com/believe/apparatus.php?birthday=bed&boot=bead"
  type: "other"
}
```

I need the result of the aggregation to look like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('000000000000000000000100')
  name: "My subject"
  description: "Lorem ipsum..."
  language: "en",
  topics: [
    {
      id: ObjectId('000000000000000000000200'),
      name: "The first topic",
      description: "Lorem ipsum...",
      content: [
        {
          _id: ObjectId('000000000000000000000300'),
          title: "Example content",
          description: "Example course in MongoDB",
          url: "http://example.com/believe/apparatus.php?birthday=bed&boot=bead"
          type: "other"
          visibility: true,
        },
        {
          url: "stackoverflow.com",
          title: "Stack Overflow",
          type: "website"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried some $unwind and $lookup combinations but none of them returned the correct result.

Is there a way to do this without using mongoose? Thank you.

Comment: you don't need mongoose, you can use your programming language driver, google nodejs mongodb driver to find it if you use javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- lookup-fields will be the `topics.content.contentId` an array with all the values we want to join
- do the lookup, matching documents will go on `results`
- and then go inside with nested `$map` to put the values that we found that they match. (the `$filter` is used to get from results the document that matched so we replaced it)

*this is a way to avoid the double unwind and keep the document structure as it is, alternative ways exists, to make the last `$set` simpler but i don't think they are faster (like single unwind and lookup and then group) with this we don't unwind at all.

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=639ba274424f6130d7f12187)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
   {"lookup-fields": 
     {"$reduce": 
       {"input": "$topics.content.contentId",
        "initialValue": [],
        "in": 
         {"$let": 
           {"vars": {"this": "$$value", "value": "$$this"},
            "in": {"$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"]}}}}}}},
 {"$lookup": 
   {"from": "content",
    "localField": "lookup-fields",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "results"}},
 {"$set": 
   {"topics": 
     {"$map": 
       {"input": "$topics",
        "as": "lv1",
        "in": 
         {"$mergeObjects": 
           ["$$lv1",
             {"content": 
               {"$map": 
                 {"input": "$$lv1.content",
                  "as": "lv2",
                  "in": 
                   {"$cond": 
                     [{"$in": ["$$lv2.contentId", "$lookup-fields"]},
                       {"$mergeObjects": 
                         [{"$first": 
                             {"$filter": 
                               {"input": "$results",
                                "cond": {"$eq": ["$$this._id", "$$lv2.contentId"]}}}},
                          "$$lv2"]},
                      "$$lv2"]}}}}]}}}}},
 {"$unset": ["lookup-fields", "results"]}])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! There is one more thing though. This aggregation seems to remove visibility key from the object with contentId. How can I modify this to keep the key?

Comment: yes you are right i forgot it, i added one more `$mergeObjects` to not replace it with the matched, but to merge them to keep all fields, i think now its ok